# Don't work alter column namecolumn varchar

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a column 'Domain' not null in table test_table, but get mistake.

```
create table test_table(
    Lastname varchar(255),
    Domain varchar(255),
    primary key(Lastname)
```

);

```
alter table test_table alter column Domain varchar(255) not null;
```

> ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "varchar")
>   '''

Comment: Or better still, don't use a reserved word as a column name; you'll be escaping it forever more. Call it WindowsDomain, DomainName, BaseUrl, or something

Comment: @Moon1705 . . . The Postgres reserved words are in the documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).  Change the name of the column.